# Use openxml sdk in c# to create xlsx files

Tags: c#, excel

I'm having a little problem creating an excel file using OpenXml SDK, I followed the instructions on [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2008/11/04/document-assembly-solution-for-spreadsheetml.aspx).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person() {FirstName="Brecht", LastName="Baekelandt", Age=29},
                new Person() {FirstName="Pieter", LastName="Baekelandt", Age=28},
                new Person() {FirstName="Leonie", LastName="Baekelandt", Age=21}
           };

        string directory = Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp", "TestFiles");

        string fileName = Path.Combine(directory, string.Format("TestFile{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss}.xlsx", DateTime.Now));

        // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
        // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.
            Create(fileName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {

            // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
            WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

            // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
            Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
                                                AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

            // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
                {
                    Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.
                                             GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                    SheetId = 1,
                    Name = "mySheet"
                };


            sheets.Append(sheet);
            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();


            UInt32 rowIndex = 0;

            foreach (var person in persons)
            {
                var row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex };

                var firstNameCell = new Cell() { CellReference = "A" + (rowIndex + 1)  };
                firstNameCell.CellValue = new CellValue(person.FirstName);
                firstNameCell.DataType = CellValues.String;

                row.AppendChild(firstNameCell);

                Cell lastNameCell = new Cell() { CellReference = "B" + (rowIndex + 1) };
                lastNameCell.CellValue = new CellValue(person.LastName);
                lastNameCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);

                row.AppendChild(lastNameCell);

                Cell ageCell = new Cell() { CellReference = "C" + (rowIndex + 1) };
                ageCell.CellValue = new CellValue(person.Age.ToString());
                ageCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);

                row.AppendChild(ageCell);

                sheetData.AppendChild(row);

                rowIndex++;
            }

            workbookpart.Workbook.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

This creates following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x:worksheet xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
<x:sheetData>
    <x:row r="0">
        <x:c r="A1" t="str">
            <x:v>Brecht</x:v>
        </x:c>
        <x:c r="B1" t="str">
            <x:v>Baekelandt</x:v>
        </x:c>
        <x:c r="C1" t="n">
            <x:v>29</x:v>
        </x:c>
    </x:row>
    <x:row r="1">
        <x:c r="A2" t="str">
            <x:v>Pieter</x:v>
        </x:c>
        <x:c r="B2" t="str">
            <x:v>Baekelandt</x:v>
        </x:c>
        <x:c r="C2" t="n">
            <x:v>28</x:v>
        </x:c>
    </x:row>
    <x:row r="2">
        <x:c r="A3" t="str">
            <x:v>Leonie</x:v>
        </x:c>
        <x:c r="B3" t="str">
            <x:v>Baekelandt</x:v>
        </x:c>
        <x:c r="C3" t="n">
            <x:v>21</x:v>
        </x:c>
    </x:row>
</x:sheetData>
</x:worksheet>
```

This should be fine, but when I open the xlsx file I get the following error:

Excel found unreadable content in [file]. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?

When I click yes, only the first person is added to the worksheet.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with indexing. Row indexing starts with `index 1`

Flowing should work.

```
      UInt32 rowIndex = 1;

      foreach (var person in persons)
      {
          var row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex };

          var firstNameCell = new Cell() { CellReference = "A" +rowIndex };
          firstNameCell.CellValue = new CellValue(person.FirstName);
          firstNameCell.DataType = CellValues.String;

          row.Append(firstNameCell);

          Cell lastNameCell = new Cell() { CellReference = "B"+rowIndex };
          lastNameCell.CellValue = new CellValue(person.LastName);
          lastNameCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);

          row.Append(lastNameCell);


          Cell ageCell = new Cell() { CellReference = "C"+rowIndex };

          ageCell.CellValue = new CellValue(person.Age.ToString());
          ageCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);

          row.Append(ageCell);

          sheetData.Append(row);

            rowIndex++;
        }
```

Comment: This is only a testcase, there wil be more objects that need to be converted into excel. Also what you're doing here is set the firstname on the first row, first column, lastname on the second row, second column etc...

Comment: It isn't working I only get the firstname of on the first row, as I said before. I need to loop over a whole list of persons, and it's the loop that isn't working. It's like whenever I want to write something on the second, third row it isn't working...

Comment: I edited my answer, I checked your code and it is not working, sorry... Also the index on cell A1 for example is the rowindex, not the column index, please read the link I provided first...

Comment: I hpdated the answer. Sorry was bit out with work so I messed the previous answer. Issue was with row indexing

Comment: This is the answer, i didn't know it woud be that simple :-)  thanks!!